# Valid looking regex pattern throws error when used with ng-pattern ?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I've found and want to use the following pattern `((ht|f)tp(s?)\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?([\w]+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([\w\-]+\.)+([\w]{2,5}))(:[\d]{1,5})?((\/?\w+\/)+|\/?)(\w+\.[\w]{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?`

[Regular expressions 101](https://regex101.com/r/yN2aB0/1#) considers it a valid regex for javascript.

Yet when I try to use it in my ng-pattern it throws the following error:

```
SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^((ht|f)tp(s?)://|~/|/)?([w]+:w+@)?([a-zA-Z]{1}([w-]+.)+([w]{2,5}))(:[d]{1,5})?((/?w+/)+|/?)(w+.[w]{3,4})?((?w+=w+)?(&w+=w+)*)?$/: Invalid group
    at new RegExp (native)
```

The exact way I'm implementing this is that I've defined the pattern in a configs file and then I'm loading it into the controller from which it is passed into the `ng-pattern`.

Comment: You need to escape forward slashes by preceding with backward slash, ex `\/`

Comment: You seem to have pasted it incorrectly. Try `ng-pattern="/^((ht|f)tps?\:\/\/|~\/|\/)?(\w+:\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]([\w-]+\.)+(\w{2,5}))(:\d{1,5})?((\/?\w+\/)+|\/?)(\w+\.\w{3,4})?((\?\w+=\w+)?(&\w+=\w+)*)?$/"`.

Comment: @stribizhev your pattern works if I put it directly in the template, but if I put it in the config and use it from there it doesn't work, why is this ?

Comment: Probably because you need to provide it as a string: `^((ht|f)tps?://|~/|/)?(\\w+:\\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]([\\w-]+\\.)+(\\w{2,5}‌​))(:\\d{1,5})?((/?\\w+/)+|/?)(\\w+\\.\\w{3,4})?((\\?\\w+=\\w+)?(&\\w+=\\w+)*)?$`

Comment: @stribizhev thank you very much now it works from config but now it doesn't want to validate https:google.com what's changed ?

Comment: XY questions are not good. `https:google.com` was not matched by the initial regex.

Comment: @stribizhev could you please convert your "need to provide it as a string" comment into an answer I got it to work and I'd like to mark it as the accepted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use the regex inside a config, you need to store it as a string. Since JS engine treats strings as C strings with escape sequences, the backslashes that escape regex metacharacters must be doubled:

```
^((ht|f)tps?://|~/|/)?(\\w+:\\w+@)?([a-zA-Z]([\\w-]+\\.)+(\\w{2,5}‌​))(:\\d{1,5})?((/‌​?\\w+/)+|/?)(\\w+\\.\\w{3,4})?((\\?\\w+=\\w+)?(&\\w+=\\w+)*)?$
```

Also, I removed all unnecessary escaping: from `/`, from `-` in `[\w-]` (as at the end/start of the character class, `-` is treated as a literal hyphen), and removed unnecessary `[...]` from `[\d]` and `[\w]`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN2aB0/3) at regex101.com.